# Detect Device Specs and Network Information

Tags: cordova

I've been doing some research on Cordova's API and I know it's possible to obtain device information, like the device's name, platform, uuid, version, etc. I also know it's possible to get information about the connection type using the API.

However, I would like to access more detailed information about the device, like details about its CPU, memory, and I would like to get the connection speed.

Is there any plugin available that allows me to have access to that kind of information? I searched and I didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no way to find out which CPU is used or how fast the internet connection is. Only the type of the internet connection can be read out by the plugin you already found.

And under iOS you can not find out, if its 2G/3G or 4G.